# Maven Grails Building with 'mvn clean install' doesn't work

Tags: maven-2, grails, maven-plugin, dependency-management, grails-maven

I've built a Maven Grails project which can be build fine using command `mvn grails:war`.

However, using the standard `mvn install` fails to work - I get exceptions complaining that a util Java class (held under the grails-app/util folder) can't compile because it can't find one of the domain classes.

I'm not using any package structures, so the domain class isn't imported to the util class.

I suppose my first question is - does Maven fully support the building of a mavenised Grails project? Should I be expecting `mvn install` to work?

My second question is - If i'm forced to build the app using `mvn grails:war` - how do I enforce this when the parent project / pom has it as a dependant module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suppose my first question is - does Maven fully support the building of a mavenised Grails project? Should I be expecting `mvn install` to work?

According to [Developer - Maven Integration](http://www.grails.org/Developer+-+Maven+Integration), yes, definitely. Did you follow the steps detailed in [Maven Integration](http://www.grails.org/Maven+Integration)? Did you use the grails archetype to create your project? Is it really using a packaging of type `grails-app`?

> My second question is - If i'm forced to build the app using `mvn grails:war` - how do I enforce this when the parent project / pom has it as a dependant module?

According to the [lifecycle](http://forge.octo.com/maven/sites/mtg/grails-maven-plugin/lifecycles.html) of a project with a packaging of type `grails-app`, the `grails:war` goal is bound to the `package` phase. In other words, nothing forces you to call `grails:war`, just call `mvn package` (and actually, you should do this) or any other standard phase posterior to package.

So, to answer your question, just use a `<packaging>grails-app</packaging>` for the grails module and maven will do its job during a reactor build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had followed the steps detailed in Maven Integration using the grails archetype to create the project.
I hadn't tried building using package (not sure why) - my knowledge of Maven is limited so thank you for explaining your answer clearly.